# Milia confirmation url not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I'm working on Udemy's Complete Ruby on Rails Developers Course taught by Mashrur. I'm working in section 10 Lecture 241 for the SaaS App Project. After running the code and signing up on my app, I tried my confirmation url but it didn't work. I went back through my code in the confirmations_controller.rb file and cleaned things up. I then recommitted the changes to git and pushed the code up. After doing that, I was unable to generate a new confirmation url in order to confirm my signup. How do I fix this?

In my confirmation href this is what I've received http://https//completerubyonrailscourse.ide.c9.io:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=...

I'm confused as to why my url starts with `"http://https//"`. Is it because I'm working in cloud 9 ide? Are you able to access why this is happening?

app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Milia::ConformationsController
  def update
    if @confirmable.attempt_set_password(user_params)

      # this section is patterned off of devise 3.2.5 confirmations_controller#show

      self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
      yield resource if block_given?

      if resource.errors.empty?
        log_action( "invitee confirmed" )
        set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_flashing_format?
          # sign in automatically
        sign_in_tenanted_and_redirect(resource)

      else
        log_action( "invitee confirmation failed" )
        respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
      end

      else
        log_action( "invitee password set failed" )
        prep_do_show()  # prep for the form
        respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render :show }
    end  # if..then..else passwords are valid
  end

  def show
    if @confirmable.new_record?  ||
       !::Milia.use_invite_member || 
       @confirmable.skip_confirm_change_password

      log_action( "devise pass-thru" )
      self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
      yield resource if block_given?

      if resource.errors.empty?
        set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_flashing_format?
      end

      if @confirmable.skip_confirm_change_password
        sign_in_tenanted_and_redirect(resource)
      end
    else
      log_action( "password set form" )
      flash[:notice] = "Please choose a password and confirm it"
      prep_do_show()  # prep for the form
    end
      # else fall thru to show template which is form to set a password
      # upon SUBMIT, processing will continue from update
  end

  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    if user_sign_in?
     root_path
    else
      new_user_session_path
    end
  end

  private 

  def set_confirmable()
    @confirmable = User.find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:confirmation_token, params[:confirmation_token])
  end
end
```

app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb

```
<p><%= t('.greeting', :recipient => @resource.email, :default => "Welcome #{@resource.email}!") %></p>

<p><%= t('.instruction', :default => "You can confirm your account email through the link below:") %></p>

<p><%= link_to t('.action', :default => "Confirm my account"),
    user_confirmation_url(:confirmation_token => @token, locale: I18n.locale) %></p>
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" and "[ask]" including the linked pages. We can't help you if you don't show us what you're doing.

Comment: if you can pinpoint the error that is raised and paste it here (along with some of your relevant code) it will be possible to help you.